# Encoding Target Column for Classification in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been working on Tensorflow for some time, but one of the things that i can't seem to figure out is how to encode the Categorical Target Column for a Model in tf.contrib.learn model.

I'm aware that we define an input function which resembles like the code below :

```
def input_fn(joined):
    continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(joined[k].values)
                     for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}

    categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(
      indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(joined[k].size)],
      values=joined[k].values,
      dense_shape=[joined[k].size, 1])
                      for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}

    # Merges the two dictionaries into one.
    feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols.items() | categorical_cols.items())
    target = tf.constant(joined[target_col].values)
    return feature_cols, target

def train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(train_frame)
def test_input_fn():
    return input_fn(test_frame)
```

This works perfectly fine for Binary Classification or for cases where we pre-encode the Target Variable either with **sklearn's** *LabelEncoder* or any other method. But how to encode that variable using tensflow so that tf.contrib.learn can accept it.

I tried changing the code for target column to the following:

```
target = tf.SparseTensor(
      indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(joined[target_col].size)],
      values=joined[target_col].values,
      dense_shape=[joined[target_col].size, 1])
```

As it is a string variable, so i thought sparse tensor should do it
But this gives the error :

```
ValueError: SparseTensor is not supported.
```

Can anyone help me in specifying what i placeholder should i use in the input function for the DNNClassifier Model for the target categorical variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNNClassifier support labels as Tensors no Sparse. Expected label is something like [[4], [5], [1]] where each value corresponds to an integer id. If you have string labels, you can use `label_keys` argument.